# CDF of conditional distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-probability, cumulative-distribution-function

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are iid normally distributed and $a$ is a scalar. What is $\Pr(Y+aX<0 | X>0)$?

Comment: Sorry about that -- I clarified that they're jointly normal.

Comment: Try this paper: http://etrij.etri.re.kr/Cyber/servlet/BrowseAbstract?vol=32&num=6&pg=965

Comment: Transform $(X,Y)\rightarrow (X,Z)$, where $Z=Y+aX$; you will obtain that $(X,Z)$ has a bivariate normal distribution with a certain mean and covariance matrix. Then use the definition ${\mathbb P}(Y+aX<0\vert X>0)=\dfrac{{\mathbb P}(Y+aX<0,X>0)}{{\mathbb P}(X>0)}=\dfrac{{\mathbb P}(Z<0,X>0)}{{\mathbb P}(X>0)}$. The numerator can be calculated using the CDF of a bivariate normal and the denominator using the CDF of the univariate normal.

Comment: If the means are zero, this requires (virtually) *no* calculation at all. Are you interested in the general case or, perhaps, this specific one?

Comment: @cardinal I guess the OP is interested in the general case because this expression appears in the paper mentioned in the [previous question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/33050/10525). I also guess he did not mean *i.i.d.*.

Comment: @Proc: Yes, that seems likely in light of that question (which I had seemed to have missed). Thanks.

Comment: In addition to cardinal's observation, if we take the meaning of iid at face value (it is, after all, an edit made by the OP), there is also a simple answer requiring very little calculation for the case $a = 1$ and $\mu_x = \mu_Y \neq 0$.